# How to implement multiple JSR-303 validation messages for the same @Constraint?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I'm using JSR-303 validation (hibernate-validator) for an entity with a few different rules to be applied. Would rather not stack up multiple `@Constraint` annotations for these and instead use a single one, e.g. `@MyEntityConstraint`.

Problem is there really needs to be a different message for each type of validation failure but the message seems inextricably associated with the annotation:

```
public @interface MyEntityConstraint {
    String message() default "A single, unchangeable message per constraint???";
    // ...
}
```

Is there any way round this or am I doomed to have:

```
@MyEntityConstraint1
@MyEntityConstraint2
// ...
@MyEntityConstraintn
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding the example code solution from what you learnt from Hardy's answer.

Comment: Thanks, glad it helped. Have now updated the solution and migrated into an answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As suggested by Hardy, this can be done simply enough using [ConstraintValidatorContext](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#_the_constraintvalidatorcontext) - as below:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(MyEntity myEntity, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    // Disable default ConstraintViolation so a customised message can be set instead.
    context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();

    return checkConstraint1(myEntity, context)
           && checkConstraint2(myEntity, context)
           //...
           && checkConstraintn(myEntity, context);
}

// Note: A private method for each constraint decreases the cyclomatic complexity.
private boolean checkConstraint1(MyEntity myEntity, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    // Default validity is true until proven otherwise.
    boolean valid = true;

    if (/*<<Insert constraint #1 conditions (about myEntity) here>>*/) {
        valid = false;
        context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(
           "<<Insert constraint #1 failure message here>>").addConstraintViolation();
    }

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: Where the `buildConstraintViolation` method contains something like: `context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{error.tmp}").addConstraintViolation();` or if the error can be tied to a property:`context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("{error.tmp}").addPropertyNode("propertyName").addConstraintViolation();`

Comment: The definition for buildConstraintViolation seems to be a big missing piece to this answer.

Comment: @Hazok Agreed - this method was used on our project for adding a custom prefix to all constraint violation error messages but this isn't needed in the example. Have now replaced it in the answer with a single line to add the constraint violation.

Comment: sorry for being late) api is ok, but if you wanna add more messages you need to validate them separately, like var condition1=checkCondition1(blah); var condition2.... otherwise it will return values until first false.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [ConstraintValidatorContext](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/beanvalidation/spec/1.1/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidatorContext.html) passed to the `isValid` method of your constraint validator. It allows you to customize the error messages which includes using different message templates depending on your validation state.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for but failed to find - many thanks.